# running sh from python file, syntax error

Tags: python, linux, sh

I'm trying to run sh-script from python file

my_script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/python

rm category.xml
```

python file

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["../my_script.sh"])
```

And I get

```
    File "../my_scrypt.sh", line 3
    rm category.xml
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your shell code. You using python interpreter `#!/usr/bin/python` and feeding it with bash commands `rm category.xml`.

Fixed shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm category.xml
```

Comment: bash and sh has difference. However, it needs to be `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: It depends on code, i think `rm` is just for testing. sh does not support many useful features of bash, but it is portable. As for me, i've never faced any problems with bash on the modern linux systems and only benefit from advanced syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You used a shebang line of `#!/usr/bin/python` on a file that isn't Python.  Change the shebang line.

Better yet, don't call out to shell scripts when you can call Python functions to do the same thing:

```
import os
os.remove("category.xml")
```

Comment: I have a shebang line, my_script.sh

`#!/usr/bin/python

rm category.xml`

Comment: Yes: it's wrong: you are saying to run the file with Python. It's not Python.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using python 2x

use commands module:

```
import commands
print commands.getoutput('sh my_script.sh')
```

if using python 3x

use subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.getoutput('sh my_script.sh'))
```

Comment: `subprocess` has been available since Python 2.4, and `commands` was deprecated in Python 2.6 (honestly, I'd never heard of it until now).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

my_script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

rm category.xml
```

Trivial approach:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['./my_script.sh']) 
>>>
```